# Open Cart - Categories

Tags: opencart

I've new to Open Cart and there's something I'm trying to accomplish.  Basically, my header has main categories.  When a user clicks a Category in the header, and is taken to the Category template, I want to list **Brands** and **Styles** in the Category sidebar, to narrow down their search.

However, Brand and Style aren't sub categories, since 1 brand could be part of many Categories.  And they don't seem to fall into Options or Attributes either.

So what's the best way to pursue this?  Does it make more sense to create a Category called "Brands", and make subcategories under that of the different brands?  And same with Style?  And then display those in the sidebar?

Or is there other functionality in Open Cart that I seem to be missing?

thanks!

Comment: I also faced this problem and I have not found better solutions than your. Moreover, i made parent category unavaible, so it does not show up in the main list and wrote some code to show it in some places i need.

Comment: Ah well thanks for that.  Im surprised there isn't a solid solution for this

Comment: I don't think this question is on-topic here. You may want to try http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart

Answer (score -1):

I certainly wouldn't create dozens of sub categories. I believe your issue may be resolved with filters. I use them in the same method you described. My cats only go one level deep and then filters allow the user to narrow the results down.

Read more here: [Product Filters](http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/626/opencart-product-filters/)

Nice extension which allows you to add ajax to those filters: [Ajax Pagination and Filters](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=9908&filter_search=ajax)